# Dulling down high gloss paint

Tags: painting

We painted out trim with high gloss paint and do not like it. Is there any way to help dull down? Or paint over with a semi gloss or satin?

Answer (score 2):

Non-woven abrasive pads (Scotchbrite® or equivalent - note that they come in a variety of fine-ness/coarseness) or steel wool are typical ways to dull gloss.

Comment: Just make sure your paint has been dry for a while (2-4 weeks) before you scrub it.

Comment: This is a lot of work and tends to leave non-uniform sheen, if not sanding patterns.

Answer (score 1):

There are products that are de-glossing agents that get brushed or wiped on. Ask for them at a paint store.
They are primarily used to de-gloss before repainting. However you may experiment with them and the result may be just what you want.  If not, you are ready to paint again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Spray it with [sugar soap](https://www.wilko.com/en-uk/decorating-diy/decorating-tools-accessories/cleaning-supplies/sugar-soap/c/sugar-soap) & wipe it down with a clean damp cloth or sponge. No abrasives required.

Granules is the cheapest, but if you only need a bit, liquid in a spray bottle is the same, just more expensive.
It's not designed specifically to knock the shine off, it's just a side effect. It will streak on old paint if you don't get sufficient coverage, but on new paint I doubt it will. Re-apply if it does.

Notes: Don't let it overspill onto metallic surfaces. Most other things should be OK.
Gloss paint in high wear areas - bannisters etc - will eventually re-gloss with wear.

Comment: Closest equivalent to sugar soap (that I know of) in North America is TSP or trisodium phosphate.